# Android Lollipop: ListView using Recycler View In Eclipse

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I want to implement **Custom ListView using RecyclerView in Eclipse**,
coz I'm more comfortable developing in Eclipse. Can anyone provide the link of "**.jar**" files required for it. I also want to achieve the material design and animation.

TIA

Comment: I too facing the same problem. could not find the recyclerView in eclipse

Comment: I think they stopped supporting Eclipse or what ??

Comment: They will start support only when releasing the lollipop version.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this example for recycle view in list view

A LayoutManager base class that greatly simplifies the development of custom layouts for RecyclerView:

https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

Answer (score 0):

---

### ECLIPSE

---

If your problem is not solved or for future readers , here is the answer: From android sdk manager download Android Support Library first.

Go to this location and copy .aar file from here

X:\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\recyclerview-v7\21.0.0

Then rename it as .zip file then unZIP it then find classes.jar file , rename it with some proper name like 'RecyclerView_v7.jar' Then copy the that .jar file in you project library. Add it to build path then restart eclipse so that it can be instantiated (not necessary but i had to do this).